# Вопрос по HTML Проекту (Джанго)

Tags: html, css

И так, не могу нормально нигде загуглить об этом. От чего зависит порядок страниц ---.html при открытии. Получилось так, что при создании проекта с другом, а точнее присоединении наших частей, изготовленная мною главная страница открывается не первой, но я не могу понять где это настраивается и от чего зависит

Comment: Добро пожаловать! urls смотрите, немного не понятно, что значит _порядок_, поскольку каждой ссылке соответсвует, как правило, html файл

Comment: Ну, имеется в виду то, что когда мы запускаем сервер "python ... runserver" и открываем ссылку, открывается не та страница, что хотелось бы

Comment: Какую ссылку? Ответьте на этот вопрос, поскольку это и есть корень проблемы. В `urls.py` четко прописывается какая ссылка, какая функция ей соответствует в `views.py`. А там уже и html файл в rendere определяется

Comment: Да и в `settings.py` может определяться входная-стартовая ссылка проекта